# How to keep cell phone number private to non white-listed numbers

Tags: calls

Is there an app or developer tool to keep phone number private when say calling Chinese take-out yet have the phone number displayed when say calling one's aunt? This would be automatic without entering any codes.

Comment: @beeshyams:  If Google wanted, it could design stock Android to prefix [CLIR commands](https://www.borgus.net/gsmkode.htm#nummerpres) onto the phone number when initiating any call.  Of course, stock Android does not do so.  But surely a third-party dialer could design in such a feature, if they wanted.

Comment: @paulj:  Do you want to send caller ID information only when dialing [contacts marked as favorites](https://www.androidcentral.com/android-101-managing-favorite-contacts)?  Or do you want something more complex and nuanced?

Comment: @unforgettableidSupportsMonica That's about correct.